# How To Override Native Android Firebase onNewToken Method In Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app with Firebase installed.
Now, I want to override the underlying native Android method "onNewToken" Firebase has (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService#onNewToken(java.lang.String))

In Android I would do something like that:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        // My new code I want to extend with
    }
}
```

How can I do this in Flutter?

I tried to add this method to build.gradle but I'm not sure if this is the right place.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Firebase documentation for [accessing the FCM registration token in Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#access_the_registration_token) that should be:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh
    .listen((fcmToken) {
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.

      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new
      // token is generated.
    })
    .onError((err) {
      // Error getting token.
    });
```

This Flutter method wraps the underlying native callback, so when `onNewToken` is called on Android it ends up firing an `onTokenRefresh` event in your Flutter app.